# Function is not a function during addEventListener

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm running an Angular 1.5 project with TypeSCript and I'm running into some bugs. I want to check the `scrollTop` value from the `.uc-card` element.

```
public container = document.querySelector(".uc-card");
```

In my `$onInit` I have:

```
public $onInit() {
    this.scroll(this.container);
    this.doSomething();   
     
    this.container.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

        console.log('scrollOnInit');                
        this.scroll(this.container);
        this.doSomething();

    });
}
```

And I have 2 functions, `scroll` and `doSomething`:

```
private doSomething() {
    console.log('doSomething');
}

private scroll(e) {
    console.log('scroll')
    console.log(e.scrollTop);
    console.log(this.container.scrollTop);
}
```

When I run the application I get the following in the console log:

```
scroll
0
0
doSomething
```

This works fine. I returns the `scrollTop` value of my `.uc-card` element. But when I scroll I get the following:

> scrollOnInit
>
> CustomerActivitiesComponent.ts:38 Uncaught TypeError: this.doSomething is not a function HTMLDivElement. (CustomerActivitiesComponent.ts:38)

The scroll function does work since the output shows `scrollOnInit`. But the `scroll` function is not called (or at least does not show any ouput) and the `doSomething` method isn't a function. But they all work fine in the onInit.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [arrow function, =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The regular function syntax does not keep the same `this` as the outside.

```
public $onInit() {
    this.scroll(this.container);
    this.doSomething();   
    // Setting event handler with arrow function guarantees `this` will be
    // the same as this it is here
    // It is like setting const _this = this, and using _this within the 
    // regular function
    this.container.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

        console.log('scrollOnInit');                
        this.scroll(this.container);
        this.doSomething();

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, haven't used the arrow functions before.